# error in sqlite "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" android

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, drop-table

so i have a problem in my DBAdapter class its just crushes when i try to open the database:
from the LogCat i guess the problem is in the onUpgrade function:

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
 int newVersion)
  {
       Log.w("SingleDBAdapter", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
       + " to "
       + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
       onCreate(db);
  }
 }
```

here is the error:

```
07-28 11:32:49.443: E/Database(1244): Failure 1 (near "122": syntax error) on 0x2435b0 when preparing 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 122'.
07-28 11:32:49.463: D/AndroidRuntime(1244): Shutting down VM
07-28 11:32:49.463: W/dalvikvm(1244): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shop.list/com.shop.list.main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "122": syntax error: **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 122**
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "122": syntax error: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 122
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.shop.list.ListDBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(ListDBAdapter.java:51)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:108)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.shop.list.ListDBAdapter.open(ListDBAdapter.java:60)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.shop.list.main.onCreate(main.java:60)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-28 11:32:49.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     ... 11 more
```

i highlighted the problem but i cant solve it :/

Comment: *the sterisks in the syntax error are not part of the LogCat i just highlighted the "main" error

Comment: that contains "DATABASE_TABLE" ?

Comment: @user1375265 Can you post full code of your DBAdapter class.

Answer (score 39):

The problem seems to be with this statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 122
```

where `122`, if it is really the name of the table to drop, is not delimited (with `'`, for instance) and thus cannot be treated as a name. But the parser expects a name there. Just enclose the name in single or double quotes, and it should work:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE + "'");
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, Great answer

Answer (score 2):

if the table name were all alpha characters, your original code would have worked.  Since the table name isn't all alpha, it needs to be surrounded with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

db = This is your database handler class

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS YourTableName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing a ';' at the end of your SQL statement

Beyond that I just checked on an sqlite3 console, it seems, that "122" is an invalid table name:

```
sqlite> drop table if exists 122;
Error: near "122": syntax error
sqlite> drop table if exists test;
sqlite>
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi Think u should use call the statement : 
"context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);"

before the call of "onCreate();"

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
 int newVersion)
  {
       Log.w("SingleDBAdapter", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
       + " to "
       + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
       context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You should change your:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
```

with:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";");
```

Also, you need to check if newVersion > oldVersion